# Ambiguous reference to member 'removeAll' in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I recently upgraded Xcode to version 7.2 and after that I am getting the error:

`var pEventIdsArray : Array = [""]`

In `viewDidLoad()`, I am using `self.pEventNamesAgoArray.removeAll()`. This is where I get an error of `Ambiguous reference to member removeAll`

Comment: pEventIdsArray or pEventNamesAgoArray ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `self.pEventIdsArray = []` to empty the array.

Is it pEventIdsArray or pEventNamesAgoArray. Check they are both the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both `removeAll()` and referencing to an empty array are valid means of emptying an array.

As shown using the Swift command-line REPL,

[image]

Your declaration `var pEventIdsArray : Array = [""]` could also be shortened to simply

`var pEventIdsArray = [""]`